# I would like to setup for an automatic email to be sent to the person who has requested the task via Google Sheets

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good day!

I would like to create a Script on Google Sheets that will take the name (as an ID) from the "Your Name" column and tie it to an email address so that once the "x" on the "Completed" column is added, it will automatically send an alert to the email address of the person who made the request.

[Screenshot of the Information collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfgYb.png)
(the data is filled in Spanish, my apologies)

Answer (score 0):

#### This should get you started

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value.toLowerCase() == "x") {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(e.user.email,"Subject","Message");
  }
}
```

I think it should be an installable onEdit since sending emails requires permission